# CSS div container background clipped when zoomed or lower resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website for a friend of mine who runs a little hotel in Hungary. [Here it is.](http://lan-na.de/)

So far I´m quite pleased with the result. My problem however is, when viewing it on my laptop at 1440x900 or zooming in on my desktop PC the background of the "box" container gets clipped and won´t extend to the bottom of the page.

I fiddled around with all sorts of values but for the life of me, I can't find the error I made. Perhaps someone will spot it instantly.

Here's the html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>www.kaiserapartman.hu</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body class="pagebody"><img class="bg" src="img/bg.jpg"/>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
<div id="flags"><table width="90" border="0" style="text-decoration:none">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.html"><img src="img/hu.jpg" width="28" height="18" alt=""/></a></td>
    <td><a href="german.html"><img src="img/de.jpg" width="28" height="18" alt=""/></a></td>
    <td><a href="english.html"><img src="img/uk.jpg" width="28" height="18" alt=""/></a></td>
    <td><a href="russian.html"><img src="img/ru.jpg" width="28" height="18" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="buttons"><table width="90" border="0" style="text-decoration:none">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="szolgal.html"><img src="img/taxi.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#105;&#110;&#102;&#111;&#64;&#107;&#97;&#105;&#115;&#101;&#114;&#97;&#112;&#97;&#114;&#116;&#109;&#97;&#110;&#46;&#104;&#117;"><img src="img/email.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kaiser.apartman?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="callto://YourUserName"><img src="img/skype.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="kapcsolat.html"><img src="img/maps.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.booking.com/hotel/hu/katser-apartman.de.html?sid=eff0e3583ef20caaee9af6506a40d7c4;dcid=4;ucfs=1;srfid=42991a3738960b3b84e19e97955bcc7a4f30f15dX1;highlight_room=" target="_blank"><img src="img/booking.png" width="90" height="90" alt=""/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="menu">
<div id="navbar" style="width:644px; float:left; clear:both;">
<li><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:#4F1700;">Kezdőlap</a></li>
<li><a href="galeria.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:#4F1700;">Galéria</a></li>
<li><a href="arak.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:#4F1700;">Árak</a></li>
<li><a href="szolgal.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:#4F1700;">Szolgáltatások</a></li>
<li><a href="kapcsolat.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:#4F1700;">Elérhetöség</a></li></div>
</div>
<div id="box">
<div id="images"><table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img/00001.jpg" width="340" height="225" alt=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img/00002.jpg" width="340" height="225" alt=""/></td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
<div id="text"><table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><h1>Üdvözöljük a hévízi Kaiser Apartman weboldalán!</h1>
    <h2>Apartmanházunk csendes fekvésű helyen, Hévíz főutcájában, a hévízi termáltótól 200 méterre található.<p>Önellátó apartmanokat kínálunk, ingyenes Wi-Fi internettel és kábeltévével, valamint privát parkolási lehetőséggel.<p>A közelben reggelizők, éttermek, kávézók, üzletek találhatók.<p>Házunktól a buszmegálló 200 méterre, Keszthely (Balaton) 7 km-re, a Hévíz-Balaton Airport repülőtér 15 km-re helyezkedik el.<p>Taxi transzfer szolgáltatást biztosítunk távolabbról érkező vendégeink részére.
Kérjen árajánlatot!</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="header"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here´s the CSS:

```html
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.pagebody {
 margin:0px;
}

.bg { 
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}

#main {
 width:100%;
 min-height:100vh;
 position:absolute;
 font:Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:bold;
 z-index:1;
}

#header {
 width:100%;
 height:70px;
 position:absolute;
 background-image:url(img/header.jpg);
 z-index:3;
}

#flags {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
 padding:0px;
}

#footer {
 width:100%;
 height:19px;
 background-image:url(img/footer.jpg);
 position:fixed;
 z-index:6;
 bottom:0px;
}

#content {
 width:1100px;
 min-height:100vh;
 z-index:2;
 position:relative;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-500px;
}

#buttons {
 width:100px;
 height:500px;
 left:1000px;
 top:70px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:5;
}

#box {
 width:1000px;
 min-height:100vh;
 height:auto;
 z-index:1;
 position:absolute;
 background:url(img/content.png);
}

#images {
 top:275px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
 left:10px;
 padding-top:5px;
 width:356px;
 height:255px;
}

#text {
 top:70px;
 left:370px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
 font-size:19px;
 font:verdana;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#4F1700;
 width:620px;
}

#logo {
 width:356px;
 height:250px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:4;
 background-image:url(img/logo.png);
}

#menu {
 width:644px;
 height:70px;
 background-color:gree;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:4;
 left:356px;
}

#navbar {
 width:644px;
 height:70px;
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 z-index:5;
 position:absolute;
 line-height:70px;
 color:#FFF;
}

#navbar li {
 padding-left:21px;
 padding-right:20px;
 margin:0;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 width:auto;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 color:#4F1700;
 text-decoration:none;
 z-index:5;
}

#navbar li:hover {
 background:url(img/hover.jpg);
 z-index:5;
 font-style:italic;
 color:#4F1700;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What You Did**

you played with zindexes of the divs and played it wrong..

**Lets look at your code:**

your div with `id = "box"` has a `z-index` 1 while its child div that contains all the text has its own `z-index` as `z-index:3` in that case when the height of the text div will increase then the height of its parent div `id = "box"` wont increase with it... I have removed the z-index of your "text" div and gave it a `margin-left:350px;` and its perfect now ... Now you can open it at any resolution zoom it in or out ... It wont clip or break ... as a matter of fact try adding more text and the size of the div will increase ...

add this to your text div

```
style = "min-height: 30px; word-break: word-wrap; float: left; margin-left: 350px;"
```

and remove its z-index and absolute property ..

Always be careful when you are changing the z-indexes of the divs ...

Comment: I shall bow down before you! Thank you very much, that was it.

Comment: @chefdiese I know how you must have felt ... I had this problem once and it really bothered me ... glad I could help .. don't forget to vote up :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You must fit the body to the viewport. you can do this by assigning the below css to body.

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I know, that's not the best way to do this, but this is what i could come up with over a quick glance. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the width of `#main` is 100% which can be less than the width of `#content` when the window is sized down.  `#content` has a left margin of `-500px`, so when the width is less than `1000px`, it get moved off to the left.
Add `min-width:1000px` to `#main` and you'll establish scrolling at anything less than `1000px`.

Comment: problem is with z-indexes  of the box div and the text div ... I dont see anything wrong with the width of anything ...